Redux-toolkit Reselect rerendering after any state change
I tried to create selector that select two variables from state and unites and returns them. But I encountered a problem, that selector causes rerendering after any state change.
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { RootState } from 'store/store.ts';

const selectWallet = (state: RootState, id: string | null) => {
  if (!id) return undefined;
  return state.wallets.list[id] || undefined;
};

const selectTotal = (state: RootState, id: string | null) => {
  if (!id) return 0;
  return state.transactions.walletsTransactionsTotals[id] || 0;
};

export const reselectWalletWithTotalBalance = createSelector([selectWallet, selectTotal], (wallet, total) => {
  if (!wallet) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (!total) {
    return wallet;
  }

  return { ...wallet, balance: wallet.balance + total };
});

export const selectWalletWithTotalBalance = (id: string | null) => {
  return (state: RootState) => reselectWalletWithTotalBalance(state, id);
};

I know that return { ...wallet, balance: wallet.balance + total }; causes rerenders, Buuut mutation selectors returning data is the point of the Reselect library (in other cases, for example when returning filtered array, no unexpected rerenders).
How to solve problem and create selector? I tryed all methods, all problems arise from creating a new object, but creating a new a object is a one of features Reselect library and I need create new object.
I tryed to reselect selectWallets and selectTotal, but nothing changed
const selectWallet = createSelector(
  [(state: RootState) => state.wallets.list, (_, id: string | null) => id],
  (walletsList, id): WalletType | undefined => {
    if (!id) return undefined;
    return walletsList[id] || undefined;
  }
);


It appears you might not be memoizing the correct selected store values. I suspect the issue is caused by the reselectWalletWithTotalBalance selecting "deeply nested" state. When that root state is updated this will trigger reselectWalletWithTotalBalance to recompute and since it potentially creates new object references each time could potentially trigger new React component rerenders even though the object properties might not have actually changed.
Try to push selection memoization up the state-tree such that the state you care about computing a populated wallet/balance from is being passed previously computed/memoized values. If the values didn't change higher up the selector-tree, then the leaf selectors aren't triggered to recompute.
Consider the following example implementation:
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { RootState } from 'store/store.ts';

// root state selectors
cost selectWallets = (state: RootState) => state.wallets;
cost selectTransactions = (state: RootState) => state.transactions;

// memoized sub-state selectors
const selectWalletsList = createSelector(
  [selectWallets],
  wallets => wallets.list,
);

const selectWalletTransactionsTotals = createSelector(
  [selectTransactions],
  transactions => transactions.walletsTransactionsTotals,
);

// memoized computed/derived state selectors
export const selectWalletWithTotalBalance = createSelector(
  [
    selectWalletsList,
    selectWalletTransactionsTotals,
    // Anonymous selector to memoize the id value
    (_state, id: string | null) => id,
  ],
  (walletList, walletTransactionsTotals, id) => {
  if (!id) return undefined;

  const wallet = walletList[id];
  const total = walletsTransactionsTotals[id] || 0;
  
  if (!wallet) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (!total) {
    return wallet;
  }

  return { ...wallet, balance: wallet.balance + total };
});

Usage:
const walletWithBalance = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => selectWalletWithTotalBalance(state, id)
);

You can make the selector-tree memoization as fine or granularly controlled as your use cases necessitate.
